# Shell script, how to process line by line for $@

Tags: sh

I am reading in inputs from a file in a shell script:

sh script_name.sh < file.txt

i know that the $@ will have the content of the file, I want to iterate through each line of the file 
since the file has new entries on every line.

I tried to do something like this:

```
for i in $@
do
   echo $i
done
```

but that seems to work.. note i just said echo $i in the example, but i want to do some other manipulation.

I am having issues with accessing elements in the $line

below is the code

```
while read line
do
        for i in $line:
        do
                echo  $i
        done
done
```

I saved this in a test.sh file and feed in the following from a test.txt file:

```
hello world
time good
world food
```

this is what i got as output:

```
hello
world:
time
good:
world
food:
```

as you can see there is an extra ":" at end of the second string

Comment: `$@` does not contain the contents of the file. It contains the command line arguments. `< file.txt` is not an argument; it's an input redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read line
do
  echo $line
done
```

Regarding the second requirement to split each line on whitespace and process each field, you need:

```
while read line
do
        for i in $line
        do
                echo  $i
        done
done
```

You must have been writing too much Python ;-), because you've accidentally got a trailing `:` in your example.

You want:

```
for i in $line
```

instead of:

```
for i in $line:
```

Comment: You could use `cut` or `awk` perhaps, if it's field extraction that you want to do. Or do you want to split into multiple lines on the space? In that case you could consider `tr ' ' '\n'` perhaps?

Comment: Oops. I think I responded to a comment that has since disappeared.

Comment: sorry, the comment accidentally got removed.

thanks works like a charm.
but there is a small issue I tried to split it via the following:



while read line
do
  for i in $line
  do
    echo $i
  done
done

this causes the last space separated item to have an extra ":" be appended to the end. not sure why

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and append some sample data? I don't see that behaviour myself running on a small test file.

Comment: You've been writing too much Python ;-) You have a trailing `:` after `$line`. You just want `for i in $line` where you've got `for i in $line:`